# Attempted to load class "EntityRepository" from namespace

Tags: symfony

I am a beginner in symfony 3. I currently have problems after installing FOSUserBundle. By creating my User entity I get this error: [Error when access to app_dev.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrxnI.jpg)

Here my entity User.php :

```
namespace SocialclockBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="SocialclockBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
  protected $id;
}
```

And my UserRepository.php :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
namespace SocialclockBundle\Repository;

/**
 * UserRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
}
```

Thank for your help !!!

florian

Comment: Please add the error text into your code rather than as a link elsewhere. Also, no need to have thankyou or your name at the bottom. And multiple exclamation are never necessary.

Answer (score 5):

You need to put the `use` after the namespace

```
namespace SocialclockBundle\Repository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
```